# Sort an array from high to low

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In the following array, I want to change the key order from high to low (so for example the year 2014 data appears first).

```
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2013
            [name] => xx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [name] => xx
        )
)
```

I have tried using `rsort`, but it returns only "1".

```
$array = rsort($array);
print_r($array);    //1
var_dump($array);   //bool(true).
```

Comment: @uuser1355300 you are using rsort in wrong way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`rsort()`](http://php.net/rsort) will only work on single-dimensional arrays. You have a 2-dimensional array, so you will need to use a different function such as [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort), which lets you use user-defined comparison function for sorting:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['year'] < $b['year'];
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [name] => xx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2013
            [name] => xx
        )

)
```

[**Working demo**](https://eval.in/218166)

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? Your explanation might help me improve the answer :)

Comment: @user1355300: Just to clarify: Did you mean to sort by years or just arrange the keys from high to low?

Comment: I meant arranging by the keys.

Answer (score 1):

`rsort` has return value of boolean, so just simple use it like this:

```
rsort($array);
```

And also, `rsort` is sorting array values in reverse order, not array keys, check the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php

So in reverse order simply just use `krsort` - Sort an array by key in reverse order:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

So your code:

```
krsort($array);
```

Comment: Who downvote??? Explain! Read once again OP question: "I want to change the key order from high to low"...

Comment: some people who even don't know PHP goes for downvote

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$array = rsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

to

```
rsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: any person who is downvoting can argue with me for this answer?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage thanks for it but I feel few peoples, who dosn't have proper knowledge but using down vote

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but this solution wouldn't work if `year` isn't the first value in the sub-array. See [this demo](https://eval.in/218175).

Comment: @RamSharma Nah. Someone's just trying to troll around.

Comment: @AmalMurali you are correct but as per the question it will work. I don't think that it won't work in this scenario.

Comment: but OP wants just change array keys from high to low, not sort by years inside array values... `krsort` is the solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($array, function($item1, $item2){
   if ($item1->year > $item2->year ) return true;
   else return false;
})
```

That´s if you wanted to order by year, if you want to order by keys uksort could be used instead